# Inconsistent behavoiur of save(commit=False) for a ModelForm in Django 2.2

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a ModelForm that selects one field and excludes the rest, one of which is a ForeignKey that I need to populate manually before saving the form.

I'm in the process of fixing a bug that one of my views has and I'm making use of the request.session object to store information so that the GET and POST method funcions will be in synced by the session in locating the model at hand instead of separately iterating though the database to pin-point what model object the submitted data should be saved for.

I'm making use of the form_object.save(commit=False) funcionality in other places of the same view and it works as I need but for some reason there is a section of the view where it just doesn't populate the extra field before calling the eventual save() method and I get an IntegrityError for that column in the database, even if it is not null=False in my model declaration right now (and I think it'd rather should be..).

So here's my ModelForm:

```
class PesoFormApertura(ModelForm):
    peso_apertura = forms.DecimalField(min_value=0,required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Peso
        fields = ('peso_apertura',)
```

here's the Model itself:

```
class Peso(models.Model):
    
    prodotto = models.ForeignKey(ProdottoPesato,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    peso_apertura = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2, blank=False, null=True)
    peso_calcolato = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    peso_chiusura = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    data = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {} - {}".format(self.prodotto.nome, self.prodotto.get_categoria_display(), self.data)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.peso_apertura == 0:
            prodotto_associato = ProdottoPesato.objects.get(pk = self.prodotto.pk)
            if prodotto_associato.permanente == False:
                prodotto_associato.delete()
                self.delete()
            else:
                super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['prodotto']
```

and here's the view part where the save() method is failing (where I placed a comment):

```
        if not 'prodotto-da-correggere' in request.session:
            for prodotto in tutti_prodotti:
                pesi_questo_prodotto_oggi = prodotto.pesi_di_oggi()
                for peso in pesi_questo_prodotto_oggi:
                    if peso.peso_apertura == None:
                        prodotto_da_elaborare = prodotto
                        peso_del_giorno = peso
                        break
            if prodotto_da_elaborare:
                finito = False
                instance_peso = peso_del_giorno
                form = PesoFormApertura(request.POST, instance = instance_peso)
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save(commit=False) # WORKS FINE
                    form.prodotto = prodotto_da_elaborare
                    form.save()
            else:
                form = PesoFormApertura(request.POST)

        else: # HERE IS WHERE IT DOESN'T BEHAVE LIKE ABOVE

            prodotto_da_elaborare = ProdottoPesato.objects.get(id=request.session['prodotto-da-correggere'])
            peso_del_giorno = None
            for peso in prodotto_da_elaborare.pesi_di_oggi():
                if peso.peso_apertura == None or peso.peso_apertura > 0:
                    peso_del_giorno = peso
                    break
            form_correzione = PesoFormApertura(request.POST, instance = peso_del_giorno)
            if form_correzione.is_valid():
                form_correzione.save(commit=False)
                form_correzione.prodotto = prodotto_da_elaborare
                form_correzione.save() # IT DOESN'T ADD THE INFORMATION TO  THE COLUMN WHEN IT SAVES
                request.session.flush()
```

The save() method works alright for the first part of the IF statement and just doesn't work for the rest of the snippet in the ELSE section.

So I'm wondering if the session has something to do with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `form.save()` it returns the instance. You should modify and save that instance.

```
if form_correzione.is_valid():
    peso = form_correzione.save(commit=False)
    peso = prodotto_da_elaborare
    peso.save()
```

You should change the other part of the view to use this approach as well. It looks like `form.prodotto = prodotto_da_elaborare` is having no effect, but you haven't noticed because `prodotto` is already set so you don't get an integrity error.

Comment: Storing the form object inside a variable as a whole when the save() method is called did the trick indeed. I'm still confused though, because I'm not doing so in the first half of the IF statement and it just seems to work fine, I don't get any error and the data is saved

Comment: In the first half, the `save()` doesn't give you an error, because the `prodotto` field was already set. However, the `form.prodotto = prodotto_da_elaborare` doesn't have any effect. If you changed it to a different value, then this new value would not be saved. Check the value in the database after saving - `peso.prodotto` will be the old value, not the new `prodotto_da_elaborare`.

Comment: To be clear, it's not *storing the form object inside a variable*. The `form.save()` returns a `Peso` instance, it's this instance that you are saving to a variable.